# How to remove duplicate space from the string using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a string like this ' Hello  <>   world '. I am using below code to remove duplicate space from the string. But it removes `<>` from the string.

```
SELECT ' Hello  <>   world ' AS Name
INTO #Temp;

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(Name)), ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' ') AS CleanName
FROM #Temp;
```

Is there any alternative?

Comment: @SRM : not a duplicate, the question you are referring removes ALL spaces, while the OP wants to retain non-duplicated spaces in the middle of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this expression instead, that relies on non-printable ASCII characters  :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(Name)),' ','CHAR(17)CHAR(18)'),'CHAR(18)CHAR(17)',''),'CHAR(17)CHAR(18)',' ') AS CleanName
FROM #Temp;
```

Yields :

```
Hello <> world
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:

```
declare @Name varchar(200)
select @Name = ' Hello  <>   world '
while charindex('  ',@Name)>0 select @Name=REPLACE(@Name,'  ',' ')
select @Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique is solid, but if you want to keep `<>`, then you can use a rare text pattern

**Example**

```
SELECT ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(Name,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
FROM #Temp;
```

**Returns**

```
Hello <> world
```

**Note**: the `ltrim(rtrim(...))` is optional